# How can I reference a list based on a variable within a data.frame?

Tags: r

I have a simple table with `emp_id` and `job_code`. I would like to return the correct `payout` based on the `job_code`

I've managed this with nested ifelse's but what if I have more `job_code`'s?

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(1)

emp_id   <- round(rnorm(100, 500000, 10000))
job_code <- sample(c('a', 'b', 'c'), 100, replace = TRUE)
result   <- sample(c(1,2,3,4), 100, replace = TRUE)

df <- data.frame(emp_id = emp_id, job_code = job_code, result = result)

job_a <- c(0, 500, 1000, 5000)
job_b <- c(0, 200, 500, 750)
job_c <- c(0, 250, 750, 1000)

# Works but sucky
df %>% mutate(payout = ifelse(job_code == 'a', job_a[result],
  ifelse(job_code == 'b', job_b[result],
    job_c[result])))
```

and `dput` if you prefer:

```
structure(list(emp_id = c(493735, 501836, 491644, 515953, 503295, 
491795, 504874, 507383, 505758, 496946, 515118, 503898, 493788, 
477853, 511249, 499551, 499838, 509438, 508212, 505939, 509190, 
507821, 500746, 480106, 506198, 499439, 498442, 485292, 495218, 
504179, 513587, 498972, 503877, 499462, 486229, 495850, 496057, 
499407, 511000, 507632, 498355, 497466, 506970, 505567, 493112, 
492925, 503646, 507685, 498877, 508811, 503981, 493880, 503411, 
488706, 514330, 519804, 496328, 489559, 505697, 498649, 524016, 
499608, 506897, 500280, 492567, 501888, 481950, 514656, 501533, 
521726, 504755, 492901, 506107, 490659, 487464, 502914, 495567, 
500011, 500743, 494105, 494313, 498648, 511781, 484764, 505939, 
503330, 510631, 496958, 503700, 502671, 494575, 512079, 511604, 
507002, 515868, 505585, 487234, 494267, 487754, 495266), job_code = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), result = c(3, 
1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 1, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 4, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 4, 3, 3, 2, 
2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 4, 1, 3, 
2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 1, 4, 2, 1, 2, 4, 2, 
3, 4, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 1, 
1, 4, 4, 1, 4, 1, 1, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1)), .Names = c("emp_id", 
"job_code", "result"), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = "data.frame")
```

What I'd like to do ideally is have the payouts within a data.frame but not sure how to reference it properly:

```
job_payouts <- data.frame(a = job_a, b = job_b, c = job_c)
# Won't work...
df %>% mutate(payout = job_payouts$job_code[result])
```

Comment: We shouldn't have to read your code to know what you're trying to do. Consider describing it in words. "the correct payout based on the job_code" is only meaningful to you.

Comment: Joins are your friend.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using tools from **tidyverse**:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

# your data
set.seed(1)

emp_id <- round(rnorm(100, 500000, 10000))
job_code <- sample(c('a', 'b', 'c'), 100, replace = TRUE)
result <- sample(c(1,2,3,4), 100, replace = TRUE)

# construct a data frame
df <- 
  data.frame(emp_id = emp_id,
             job_code = job_code, 
             result = result,
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# your jobs
job_a <- c(0, 500, 1000, 5000)
job_b <- c(0, 200, 500, 750)
job_c <- c(0, 250, 750, 1000)

# construct a data frame
my_job <- 
  data.frame(job_a, job_b, job_c) %>% 
  gather(job, value) %>% 
  group_by(job) %>% 
  mutate(result = 1:n(),
         job_code = str_replace(job, "job_", "")) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  select(-job)

# join df and my_job into my_results table
my_results <-
  left_join(df, my_job)
```

**Results**:

```
my_results %>% tbl_df

Source: local data frame [100 x 4]

   emp_id job_code result value
    (dbl)    (chr)  (dbl) (dbl)
1  493735        a      3  1000
2  501836        a      1     0
3  491644        b      2   200
4  515953        a      2   500
5  503295        a      2   500
6  491795        b      4   750
7  504874        b      1     0
8  507383        a      4  5000
9  505758        a      1     0
10 496946        c      2   250
..    ...      ...    ...   ...
```

Answer (score 10):

This can be achieved through the super cool method of matrix indexing in base R which is extremely fast and efficient.

```
# build jobs payout lookup matrix, by hand (see edit below for an extension)
jobs <- rbind(job_a, job_b, job_c)

# add row names to the matrix for convenient reference
rownames(jobs) <- levels(df$job_code)

# get payout using matrix indexing
df$payout <- jobs[cbind(df$job_code, df$result)]
```

This returns

```
# print out first 6 observations
head(df)
  emp_id job_code result payout
1 493735        a      3   1000
2 501836        a      1      0
3 491644        b      2    200
4 515953        a      2    500
5 503295        a      2    500
6 491795        b      4    750

# print out jobs matrix for comparison
jobs
  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
a    0  500 1000 5000
b    0  200  500  750
c    0  250  750 1000
```

There are a couple of details that worth mentioning.

1. The `data.frame` function converts the job_code character vector, so that `df$job_code` is a factor variable where labels are associated with the natural numbers 1, 2, 3, ... By default, levels of the factor are ordered alphabetically by label so, in this example, the label "a" corresponds to 1, "b" to 2, and "c" to 3. You can use the `levels` function to find the order of the factor variable and construct the jobs matrix following that template.
2. The jobs matrix is used as a lookup table. It is constructed so that these integers refer to row numbers of the jobs matrix. Then, the columns can be subset as you do with the original payout vectors.
3. `cbind(df$job_code, df$result)` forms a 2 by `nrow(df)` (100) matrix which is used to look up the `nrow(df)` payoff values for each employee from the jobs matrix using matrix indexing. The [R intro manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Index-matrices) has a nice intro section on matrix indexing and additional details can be found in `help("[")`.

---

**Edit:** *Automating the construction of the lookup matrix*

In the comments to this answer, the OP expresses concern that building the lookup matrix (which I called "jobs"), by hand would be tedious and prone to error. To address these valid concerns, we can use a somewhat obscure argument to the `mget` function, "ifnotfound." This argument allows us to control the output of elements of the list that `mget` returns when they are present in the vector of names, but not present in the environment.

In the comments, I suggested using `NA` to fill in missing levels in the comment below. We can extend this by using `NA` as the input for "ifnotfound."

Suppose `df$job_code` is a factor that has levels "a", "aa", "b", and "c" in that order. Then we build the look up matrix as follows:

```
# build vector for example, the actual code, using levels(), follows as a comment
job_codes <- c("a", "aa", "b", "c") # job_codes <- levels(df$jobcodes)

# get ordered list of payouts, with NA for missing payouts
payoutList <- mget(paste0("job_", job_codes), ifnotfound=NA)
```

which returns a named list.

```
payoutList
$job_a
[1]    0  500 1000 5000

$job_aa
[1] NA

$job_b
[1]   0 200 500 750

$job_c
[1]    0  250  750 1000
```

Note that `payoutList$job_aa` is a single NA. Now, build the matrix from this list.

```
# build lookup matrix using do.call() and rbind()
jobs.lookupMat <- do.call(rbind, payoutList)

jobs.lookupMat
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
job_a     0  500 1000 5000
job_aa   NA   NA   NA   NA
job_b     0  200  500  750
job_c     0  250  750 1000
```

The rows of the matrix are properly ordered according to the levels of the factor `df$job_code`, conveniently named, and `NA`s fill in rows wherever there is no payout.

Comment: Thanks, this is a helpful start. I'm not too sure about depending on the ordering of variables to make sure this process works though. While this is a trivial case, a new job code 'aa' could be created that would be in the source data, but not in my payout table. Ideally, I'd like to match on job_code, even if it means restructuring how the payout grid looks.

Comment: Right. In such cases, for this method, you would add a row of NAs for each job_code level that was missing in the payout info. Something like `jobs <- rbind(job_a, NA, job_b, job_c)` would work for a missing level "aa".

Answer (score 3):

Without changing your data structure, you can do this by defining a function:

```
job_search <- function(code){
  var_name <- paste0("job_",code)
  if (exists(var_name)){
    return(get(var_name))
  }else{
    return(NA)
  }
}

library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, payout := job_search(job_code)[result], by = .(emp_id)]
df
        emp_id job_code result payout
  1: 493735        a      3   1000
  2: 501836        a      1      0
  3: 491644        b      2    200
  4: 515953        a      2    500
  5: 503295        a      2    500
  6: 491795        b      4    750
  7: 504874        b      1      0
  8: 507383        a      4   5000
  9: 505758        a      1      0
 10: 496946        c      2    250
 11: 515118        c      1      0
 12: 503898        a      1      0
 ...
```

However, this is a fairly unstable way to keep your data, and the paste + get syntax is convoluted.

A better way to store your data would be in a lookup table:

```
library(data.table)

job_a <- data.frame(payout = c(0, 500, 1000, 5000))
job_b <- data.frame(payout = c(0, 200, 500, 750))
job_c <- data.frame(payout = c(0, 250, 750, 1000))

job_lookup <- rbindlist( #this is a data.table
  l = list(a = job_a,b = job_b,c = job_c),
  idcol = TRUE
)

# create your result index
job_lookup[, result := 1:.N, by = .id]
job_lookup
    .id payout result
 1:   a      0     1
 2:   a    500     2
 3:   a   1000     3
 4:   a   5000     4
 5:   b      0     1
 6:   b    200     2
 7:   b    500     3
 8:   b    750     4
 9:   c      0     1
10:   c    250     2
11:   c    750     3
12:   c   1000     4

# merge to your initial data.frame
merge(df, job_lookup, by.x = c("job_code","result"), by.y = c(".id","result"), all.x = TRUE)

    job_code result emp_id payout
1          a      1 505758      0
2          a      1 501836      0
3          a      1 503898      0
4          a      1 494575      0
5          a      1 487464      0
6          a      1 503700      0
7          a      1 505939      0
8          a      1 503330      0
9          a      1 512079      0
10         a      1 481950      0
11         a      1 507685      0
12         a      1 490659      0
...
```